In the movies "The Godfather", is their spoken Italian authentic and correct?
There are two questions on Movies & TV related to Italian language:

In the movies, The Godfather I and II, is their spoken Italian authentic?
Why were there no English subtitles provided during the conversation between Michael and Sollozzo?

It probably would take a native speaker to make the difference between Italian and Sicilian (if any), and to tell whether their dialogue is correct or not. This is one of the scenes where they speak Italian. Is this proper language?
If it helps, there are also many translations available (on DVD, some countries provide the user with subtitles, some don't), and here's one of them.

They are speaking Sicilian. Padri is used where in Italian would be padre and I hear an eo instead of io. I am not Sicilian; I could understand the meaning of what said (except some phrases), but that is not "proper" Italian.

In the theater they say udimi instead of andiamo (let’s go) and that’s Sicilian
